# Wordpress Double Pages ID inside the Code

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm working on a theme similar to getBootstrap.com page. The issue I'm facing is:

I'm trying to display specific content in the purple section by using the following:

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=39"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The top content are brought from page ID 39 <-- this is a page template, as I will be creating multiple templates to display specific content at the top from other pages as well, if there is another way please help otherwise...

I also have this code after the top content which is the default content page (The default page content from the WordPress WYSIWYG editor).

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

But it is getting page ID 39 content.

I want to the page ID I'm in contents at the bottom (white space) beside the page ID 39 in the (purple space).

I hope my question is clear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lspz.png

**Solution Found:**

```
<?php 
$id=39; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $content;  
?>
```

Comment: Post your solution in the answer section and accept it as well.

Comment: Thanks! I did and waiting 11 hours so I can Accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Used this:

```
<?php 
$id=39; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $content;  
?>
```